# Style for ImageButton using material design

Tags: java, android, xml, android-imagebutton

I have the following v21\styles.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
            <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
            <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
            <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/brown</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I'd like to give a certain color to ImageButtons. Is there a simple solution that would look like kind of like this?

```
<item name="colorImageButton">@color/brown</item>
```

Is it possible to do this simply? If it's not possible, how am I supposed to manage this?

(Sorry, I'm working on my first app ever so this question might seem stupid to some of you)

Comment: Generally ImageButtons are basically all image. What do you mean 'give a certain color to ImageButtons'? Do you mean a background color?

Comment: hi, imagebuttons are like buttons and imageView together. Yes you can add simply background color to them. But I suppose that you have a desired effect which you want to implement to your app, please show me ;-)

Comment: yes I mean background color :) I'd like all my ImageButtons to have the same background color. That's all